# Check if checkbox in checkbox array is checked

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have an array of checkboxes. If there is a checked checkbox, it will be added into a string of text. Here is my code:

```
  var a = $(this).closest('tr').parent().closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"].CheckedArray');

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].is(':checked')) {
                list= list+ a[i].value + ", ";
            }
            alert(list);
        }

        <table id="" class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-horizontal form-inline">
            <input class="CheckedArray" type="Checkbox" value="' + Id + '" id="CheckedArray" name="CheckedArray" />Select<div class="form-group"><label for="" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label><label for="" class="control-label col-sm-4">PD No: </label><div class="col-sm-3"><input name="PDNo" class="form-control input-sm " id="PDNo" type="text" /></div></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I used `checked` as condition but it doesnt show any alert. I dont want to use filter function because i need the iteration value to shows other input.

Comment: can you add your HTML? which includes the table

Comment: I am using jquery to define the input. but I have edited the question

Comment: *"I have an array of checkboxes."* An array of  ***checkboxes*** usually implies more than one checkbox, yet I see only one checkbox called `#CheckedArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the location for checked checkbox but you will never get the element if you are not using $ sign..

Use the below code and everything will work out.

$(a[I]).prop("checked");

Comment: it works! thank you. i just want to ask, if i want to assign a text into an input located at the same row as checked checkbox, i use the same code but i didnt works? `$(b[i]).val("hello");`

Comment: You can use the "closest" or "find" attribute to get the element which is next to check box. And then assign the text.... For example. $(a[i]).find(":input").Val("your text box");

Comment: Let me know your input type which is next to your check box.. so that I can send you the exact code....

Comment: The input is `PDNo`. It is stated in the question. What I actually want to do is, the first row of checked checkbox input need to be keyed in by user. But if the user check another checkbox, the input on that particular row is auto filled using the first input value.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )
{
  \\Code_here
}
```

Or

```
if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )
{
  \\Code_here
}
```

Both will work.Try adding $ sign in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
     $(".CheckedArray").change(function()
       {
         console.log( $(this).prop("checked"),$(this).attr("id") );

       });

    });
     </script>

<table id="" class="table">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="form-horizontal form-inline">
    <input class="CheckedArray" type="Checkbox" value="' + Id + '" id="CheckedArray" name="CheckedArray" />Select<div class="form-group"><label for="" class="control-label col-sm-1"></label><label for="" class="control-label col-sm-4">PD No: </label><div class="col-sm-3"><input name="PDNo" class="form-control input-sm " id="PDNo" type="text" /></div></div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```